# Internet Explorer 10 List items spaces become breaks

Tags: html, internet-explorer, line

Really stumped with this, might be me being a bit dim.

Consider this html:

```
        <div id="ebt_info_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-h"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-i"></i> FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-s"></i> Feedback</a></li>            
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-b"></i> Bookmark Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-c"></i> Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


        <div id="ebt_search">
            <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" /><button class="ebt_input_button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div><!-- / End #ebt_search -->

    <div class="ebt_clear"></div>

</div> <!-- / End #ebt_info_nav -->
```

And this CSS:

```
#ebt_info_nav {
width: 98%;
line-height:30px;
margin: 0 1% 1% 1%;
background: #336699;
border-radius: 6px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(44, 85, 128) 0%, rgb(51, 102, 153) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(44, 85, 128) 0%, rgb(51, 102, 153) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(44, 85, 128) 0%, rgb(51, 102, 153) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(44, 85, 128) 0%, rgb(51, 102, 153) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(44, 85, 128) 0%, rgb(51, 102, 153) 100%); 
padding: 0.5% 0;   
} 


#ebt_info_nav ul {
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
width: 70%;
}

#ebt_info_nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
margin: 0 0.25%;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
} 

#ebt_info_nav ul li a {
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
padding: 0.5% 3%;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #003366;
} 

#ebt_info_nav ul li a:hover {
background: #fff;
color: #336699;
border-radius:6px;
text-shadow: none;
}  

#ebt_search { 
float: right;
padding: 0 1%;
}
```

Image here
http://i44.tinypic.com/2v9aphl.png

Why would IE 10 make the items wrap or replace the spaces with line breaks? I have removed the fontello icons and it still happens with just the text.

Any pointers will be gratefully received.

Comment: You might be better off using `display:inline-block`, rather than `float:left`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've given us, I think you mean something like this??

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eIfiF

Sorry, let me tell you what I did.

To get it to stop breaking and going on a new line, I took away the small `%` paddings, and did `display:inline-block` so that  it fit better rather than `float:left;`

If you need/want to keep the `float:left` attributes, you can simply just remove this line and it /should/ work:

`padding: 0.5% 3%;`

Comment: Great, the padding change alone fixed it for me. Any idea why this happens? Appreciate the reply and cure.

Comment: If you want the padding, apply it to `#ebt_info_nav ul li` rather than `#ebt_info_nav ul li a` and it will work! No idea why it does it with the `a` though! Sorry @BernieDavies

Comment: Thanks Alex - appreciated.